# Plane wave expansion and time independence of Hamiltonian

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, quantum-field-theory, hamiltonian, plane-wave

I am confused by a statement made in "Lectures on Quantum Field Theory", 2nd edition by Ashok Das. The author is describing the interaction picture (IP) of QFT. In equation (6.52) he shows that the free part ( denoted by subscript 0 ) of the Hamiltonian is independent of time ( the superscript S is for Schrodinger picture):

$$ H_0^{IP}(t) = e^{i H_0^{(S)}t} H_0^{(S)} e^{-i H_0^{(S)}t} = H_0^{(S)} \tag{6.52}$$

Now, on page 228 he says: "We note from (6.52) that the free Hamiltonian in the interaction picture is time dependent and ,therefore, the field operators can have a plane wave expansion".

**Question: What does the time independence of Hamiltonian have to do with plane wave expansion? Can't we express a field as sum of plane waves if the Hamiltonian is time-dependent?**

This is my guess. The plane wave solutions would be the eigenstates of the Hamiltonian. But if Hamiltonian is changing from time to time, then the eignestates will also keep changing. Thus we can't have plane wave expansion if Hamiltonian is time-dependent.